# Voting popup dialog's "X" contains more space on top than on the bottom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message

When voting *(up or down)* on a question, I noticed it contains more space on top of the `"x"` to close the popup dialog box than at the bottom.

Is this a (CSS) bug?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It would look better if it contained the same amount of space top and bottom.

Comment: The dialog was probably made with the mindset that it'd always contain enough text to wrap to the next line

Comment: @SeinopSys TBH, I don't remember seeing it going into two lines and if it does align properly if/when that happens.

Comment: I've seen that dialog many times, but I've never seen that spacing issue.

Comment: @TinyGiant It's a first time for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. There was bunch of similar issues on meta about this popup dialog. It is now fixed or prod.

Comment: My pleasure. Now to wait and see when it does pop up again. I'm sure it will be fine, so I'll accept the answer, thanks and *cheers*. Btw, something I didn't include in my question was about it being related to answers also. I take it that that is using the same styling/coding whether it be for questions and/or answers, correct? Another thing is that there were instances where the background was blue instead of red. Just thought I'd add those additional details.

Comment: That is correct - all those popup messages are based on the same code. [Gotta fix 'em all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVp-zIONsrs)!

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the video; the song's a real waker-upper. I can put my Espresso on ice now ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: [Coffee on rocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rog8ou-ZepE), sir!

Comment: Btw, I noticed this also applies to (voting) deleting posts where the similar warning appears, which I tried / experienced just a few minutes ago. Looks great, thanks again and for that other cool vid ;-) Edit: There is one thing I noticed though. Why the voting popup disappears on its own, but not for the voting to delete where one needs to click the "x". Is this by design?